# Magento limitations for products and customers

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am new in magento. I want to make a site in which approximately million products should be uploaded and can also handle around 20 million customers like as in flipkart or snapdeal etc.

Is magento platform will fulfill my requirement or i will go for some other framework?

Comment: You can opt for Magento enterprise edition. I have worked on a project which had 28 Lakh products in catalog.

Comment: Thanks muk. Can you please send me any reference link so that i can know more about the enterprise edition and can clear my doubts

Comment: But magento enterprise edition is payable around $15,500. Whether it is valid for life time once it is purchased or some time limit is there?

Comment: @Prince your question is based on suggestion and opinion. What Muk said is correct but you must analyse enterprise edition to check its feasibility with your requirement. Also how would you go on uploading 10 lakh of products and manage 2 crore users ?

Comment: Yes enterprise edition is fulfilling my requirement. Its our requirement as per our client so would u please tell me whether enterprise edition is valid for life time or for a year once it is purchased? can you please explain

Comment: @Prince Got to this link http://magento.com/products/overview#enterprise  Request for a demo.

Comment: Ya i already go through this. But I am confused in price system for enterprise edition. Can you please clear me out.

Comment: @Prince http://enterprise.magento.com/explore/contact-sales  Using the details given on this link you can contact Magento for pricing.They will surely help you.

Comment: As you have said before that u have already worked in enterprise edition so you better know about the price system for enterprise edition

Answer (score 0):

**What is Magento Enterprise Edition?**

Let's start with the basics: Magento EE is not an 'inexpensive' solution. It costs about a `$16,000` a year (check [Magento's website for specifics](http://enterprise.magento.com/explore/contact-sales)).

**So, what do you get for this investment? Among other items:**

- A mobile-friendly store
- A service level agreement (SLA) with Magento for support (see the
  note below)
- Improved search functionality with Solr: definitely a worthwhile
  investment given the poor default search in Community Edition!
- Full page caching: simply, your website loads faster. And faster
  websites mean more sales.
- Enhanced content management and catalogue management tools

It's worth noting that the support provided by the `SLA` is limited to Magento's core, whereas in my experience, problems are often caused by `third party extensions` installed which would then require additional development time at extra cost to fix.

**So, is Magento Enterprise Edition for you?**

If you're planning a ground breaking store and you turn over more than around `£100,000 – £200,000` per year, then probably!

The enhanced `search feature`, `catalogue (product) management tools` and `page caching` itself are probably worth the fee alone.

However, if you're operating on a smaller scale, that money may be better invested by retaining your Magento Community Edition store, and looking at `site improvements` to improve your `conversion rate` and `search engine optimisation` of key pages in your website.

Some useful links

[MAGENTO ENTERPRISE DEMO REQUEST](http://enterprise.magento.com/explore/demo)

[Magento General and Enterprise Feature List](http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/Magento%20Full%20Features%20List%20052714.pdf)

[Comparison Chart](http://www.logicsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Magento-Editions-Comparison-01122015.pdf)

Comment: ok i agree. But is it possible to upload huge no of products in community edition......The site will hang and too slow as well

Comment: @Prince you can not have the best of both worlds. The key is to carefully evaluate your current needs and long-term plans to find the right solution for you. Once you make that selection, the next step is to determine how you will manage the data flow between Magento, your other sales channels and your back-end systems

Comment: Enterprise Edition (EE) is the same as Community (CE) but with added features like those listed above.  It does nothing to help with the number of records, that is most likely limited by the performance of your MySQL server.  Both editions work with MySQL in the same way (except for Solr search).

Comment: @ clockworkgeek yes i understand but if i am using community edition then in future i will face a lot of problems mainly for site loading and for speed. It is ok if i will go for opencart...........what do you say?

Comment: As opencart provides features like
    Unlimited Categories
    Unlimited Products
    Unlimited Manufacturers
    Multi Currency
    Multi Language
    Product Reviews
    Product Ratings
    Open Source
    Free Documentation
    Templatable
    Automatic Image Resize
    20+ Payment Gateways
    8+ Shipping Methods

Comment: I have not used opencart so cannot say.  There are plenty of blogs on the net which compare these better than I ever could.

Comment: @Prince whichever framework you choose, you might face speed issues. There could be 101 ways to speed up your 'X framework ' e-commerce website. Google is using site speed in web search ranking. Speed is important for your site, and not only for Google but mainly for the User Experience (UX) on your site irrespective of the framework you are using.